# sudden issue with METAfont | MikTeX

Tags: miktex, metafont, yap

So, nary a problem for quite a while, but for some reason, today, when I try to use yap in MikTeX to look at a .dvi file, yap throws the following error, suggesting that modes.mf is missing. [Using 64-bit MikTeX 2.9.7250 under Windows 10 Pro.]

```
 MiKTeX Problem Report
 Message: METAFONT modes cannot be initialized because 'modes.mf' is missing.
 Data:
 Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\mfmodes.cpp
 Line: 52
 MiKTeX: 2.9.7250
 OS: Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit, build 18363
```

I'm puzzled, because modes.mf is definitely there. But what's really odd is that if I simply try to start yap.exe, all on its own, it throws the same error. Even if I 'refresh' everything using the MikTex console.

Any suggestions, before I do a complete re-install of MikTeX (which isn't that big of a deal, but stilll...)?

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with the latest metafont update in MikTeX. There was one on 2020-01-29. Maybe you could try rolling back your metafont version to the previous one?

Comment: I just did a re-install, using an older installer, and didn't see METAFONT in the list of updates? Where should I be looking for it (so I don't 'update' it?).

Comment: Just found it -- the only way I know of to roll back an individual package is to re-install from 'one step back', and update everything except for the problem package. Seems to have solved the problem (based on a few quick tests). Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Re-installing, and then updating everything *except* METAFONT did, in fact, solve the problem. I've filed a report with the MikTeX devs:  https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/160

Comment: Windows 10, current miktex, had the same problem right today after updating miktex. Solved it in two steps. 1 - Installed package `modes', still had some problems as yap continued to look for modes.mf in metafont although in different way. Then 2 - created a folder  metafond/misc in my additional mytex folder and copied modes.mf to that new folder. Then refresh the file database and oops yap works!

Answer (score 8):

They changed the `modes.mf` file to the `modes` package. If you go to the MiKTeX console and install this package everything should work just fine, you don't need to re-install anything.

Comment: Yeah - that works! thanks a lot!
Rudi Radler
Germany